# Call a wave file in PowerShell and set the focus back to the original window with Alt+Tab

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script to call a wave sound file run in background and at the same time change the focus back to the original window. But my script is not changing focus back to the main window. Can anyone help me here?
My script looks like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$mediaPlayer = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
$mediaPlayer.SoundLocation='C:\temp\ring\2Ring.wav'
$mediaPlayer.PlaySync()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$wsh.Sendkeys("%{TAB}")
```

Comment: You need to know the process window of the app you want to set focus to before you can set focus on it. There are many articles on how to get the Windows or Process ID of a process and [how to use SendKeys to activate it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27sendkeys+app+activate%27&t=h_&ia=web). Just search via the search box above or generally via your favorite search engine. This is really not a PowerShell-specific issue, as the steps are the same as they would be using legacy VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for guiding me to the right direction.
My final code became like this:

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate((Get-Process -Name notep*').MainWindowTitle)
    $mediaPlayer = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
    $mediaPlayer.SoundLocation='C:\temp\ring\2Ring.wav'
    $mediaPlayer.PlaySync()
```